# Get Values from anonymous type

Tags: c#, datagridview

In one button I made a query where I selected these 3 values: idStudent, name, lastName and bounded to a DataGridView and now I get those values again to use them in another button with this:

```
var Selected = dgvShow.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

And the result from Selected is this:

```
{idStudent = 31, name = "John", lastName = "Travolta"}
```

The above result is an Anonymous Type, so how can I  get those values and show them in a TextBox?

Also:
Can I get a single value from that var ("Selected")?

Is it possible or I have to change my code?

PS: I'm using Entity Framework, C#

Comment: PS: this Selected attribute only show: ToString(), GetType(), GetHashCode() and Equals() methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use your properties as an anonymous type you can cast it to a dynamic.

Eg:

```
var Selected = dgvShow.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
var objDynamic = (dynamic)Selected;
Console.WriteLine(objDynamic.idStudent);
```

I would recommend using a model instead of an anonymous type and unbox your DataBoundItem into your model, it will benefit accessibility of your property names via IntelliSense and make it more manageable for other people to maintain.

Comment: I use it but I have to get these values to do another action. In addition it's a school project and it's the last event, action of the program

Comment: Np. Good luck with your school project.